# Show Inactive Product records to user who does not have edit access

Tags: security, profile, standard-objects, customization

Is there a way to show inactive products to user who does not have edit access to same ?

I could have given edit access to products on user's profile but then they will also have access to activate/deactivate products, which they are not supposed to do, according to my requirement.

Comment: and giving those users only Read access to Products doesn't work?

Comment: With only Read access, users cannot view inactive products.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would appear this is not possible - users will need Edit access and you'll need validation rules to prevent them from Editing any Products (different page layouts by user profile can help as well with visible fields set to read only)

Such a validation rule might be something like:

```
$Profile.Name = 'GeneralUser' &&  ISCHANGED( IsActive )
```

with error message

```
You don't have permissions to (de)activate a Product
```

See https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giIAAAY

There is an Idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IVh0